# Android & Cocos2d-x: Exceptions on System.loadLibrary(libName); & onLoadNativeLibraries();

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, cocos2d-x, logcat

Well, I finally got cocos2d-x into the IDE, and now I can make minor changes like change the label text.

But when trying to add a sprite, the app crashes on my phone (Galaxy Ace 2), and I can't make sense of the debug output.

I followed [THIS](http://youtu.be/2LI1IrRp_0w) video to set up my IDE, and i've literally just gone to add a sprite in the template project...

Could someone help me fix this please:

```
07-22 13:22:32.310: D/PhoneWindow(22070): couldn't save which view has focus because the focused view org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView@405240c8 has no id.
07-22 13:22:32.930: V/SurfaceView(22070): org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView@405240c8 got app visibiltiy is changed: false
07-22 13:22:32.930: I/GLThread(22070): noticed surfaceView surface lost tid=12
07-22 13:22:32.930: W/EglHelper(22070): destroySurface()  tid=12
07-22 13:22:32.960: D/CLIPBOARD(22070): Hide Clipboard dialog at Starting input: finished by someone else... !
07-22 13:23:05.190: W/dalvikvm(22133): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001e578)
07-22 13:23:05.190: E/AndroidRuntime(22133): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-22 13:23:05.190: E/AndroidRuntime(22133): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load cocos2dcpp: findLibrary returned null
07-22 13:23:05.190: E/AndroidRuntime(22133):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:429)
07-22 13:23:05.190: E/AndroidRuntime(22133):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:554)
07-22 13:23:05.190: E/AndroidRuntime(22133):    at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxActivity.onLoadNativeLibraries(Cocos2dxActivity.java:66)
07-22 13:23:05.190: E/AndroidRuntime(22133):    at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxActivity.onCreate(Cocos2dxActivity.java:80)
07-22 13:23:05.190: E/AndroidRuntime(22133):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1050)
07-22 13:23:05.190: E/AndroidRuntime(22133):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
07-22 13:23:05.190: E/AndroidRuntime(22133):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
07-22 13:23:05.190: E/AndroidRuntime(22133):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
07-22 13:23:05.190: E/AndroidRuntime(22133):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
07-22 13:23:05.190: E/AndroidRuntime(22133):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-22 13:23:05.190: E/AndroidRuntime(22133):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-22 13:23:05.190: E/AndroidRuntime(22133):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
07-22 13:23:05.190: E/AndroidRuntime(22133):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-22 13:23:05.190: E/AndroidRuntime(22133):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-22 13:23:05.190: E/AndroidRuntime(22133):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
07-22 13:23:05.190: E/AndroidRuntime(22133):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:670)
07-22 13:23:05.190: E/AndroidRuntime(22133):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-22 13:23:07.200: I/dalvikvm(22133): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
07-22 13:23:07.200: I/dalvikvm(22133): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Thanks

---

P.S. `Cocos2dxActivity.java` has errors on line 66 & 80.

Line 66 is `System.loadLibrary(libName);` and line 80 is `onLoadNativeLibraries();` In line 65 it declares lib name as `String libName = bundle.getString("android.app.lib_name");`

Also, I can see in the Manifest that the key information is:

```
<!-- Tell Cocos2dxActivity the name of our .so -->
<meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name"
    android:value="cocos2dcpp" />
```

I do have the NDK, and I hooked it up in my ./bash_profile. But I did just notice that the console says:

```
python /Users/damianwilliams/Desktop/KittyKatch/proj.android/build_native.py -b release all 
NDK_ROOT not defined. Please define NDK_ROOT in your environment
```

But I know I have it in my bash since my bash profile says:

```
# Add environment variable COCOS_CONSOLE_ROOT for cocos2d-x
export COCOS_CONSOLE_ROOT=/Users/damianwilliams/Desktop/Android-Development-Root/cocos2d-x-3.2rc0/tools/cocos2d-console/bin
export PATH=$COCOS_CONSOLE_ROOT:$PATH

# Add environment variable NDK_ROOT for cocos2d-x
export NDK_ROOT=/Users/damianwilliams/Desktop/Android-Development-Root/android-ndk-r10
export PATH=$NDK_ROOT:$PATH

# Add environment variable ANT_ROOT for cocos2d-x
export ANT_ROOT=/Users/damianwilliams/Desktop/Android-Development-Root/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin
export PATH=$ANT_ROOT:$PATH
```

But I've no idea what to do with that information or if I've built it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There Is your Error :

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load cocos2dcpp: findLibrary returned null //  <-- error
07-22 13:23:05.190: E/AndroidRuntime(22133):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:429)
07-22 13:23:05.190: E/AndroidRuntime(22133):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:554)
07-22 13:23:05.190: E/AndroidRuntime(22133):    at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxActivity.onLoadNativeLibraries(Cocos2dxActivity.java:66) // <-- file name : line number
07-22 13:23:05.190: E/AndroidRuntime(22133):    at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxActivity.onCreate(Cocos2dxActivity.java:80) // <-- file name : line number
```

Easy Way to Find that Where is Your Error.... Look For brackets `( )`..
If it contains your Activity or Java File Name..it means there can be error...

Here... there may be error in  **`Cocos2dxActivity.java`** file.. in line 66 or 80

Comment: MMmmmm.... Good thinking batman...! Line 66 is `System.loadLibrary(libName);` and 80 is `onLoadNativeLibraries();` But I've no idea what to do with that information. BTW, in line 65 it declares lib name as `String libName = bundle.getString("android.app.lib_name");`

Comment: ok. How can I resolve? I updated the question to include a link to the video I used for setting up my IDE and getting all the libraries added...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are going to like the answer.  Your code depends on a library that is, probably, native code.  The call at line 66 attempts to load the native binary and fails.

There are, of course, any number of reasons that the load could fail.  Here are a few:

- You didn't build the library and it is not in your .apk
- Each platform has its own way of constructing the library file name, from the root name (e.g., foo.dylib, libfoo.so, etc).  The file exists but has the wrong name.
- The library is not binary compatible with the hardware you are using: the load fails

You are going to have to find out what filename is passed in that bundle, at the key "android.app.lib_name", and determine how to build the loadable library it represents.

Comment: Nope.... I like that answer just fine...! lol. I didn't understand most of it but i'll do some research to see if I can find out more to build up the question a little. BTW, as you can imagine, I'm literally only just starting out and everything I've done so far is in this video: http://youtu.be/2LI1IrRp_0w

Comment: @KittyKatch Search for Android NDK.

Comment: Yeah, I have the NDK, and I hooked it up in my ./bash_profile. But I did notice that the console says: `python /Users/damianwilliams/Desktop/KittyKatch/proj.android/build_native.py -b release all 
NDK_ROOT not defined. Please define NDK_ROOT in your environment` But I know I have it in my bash since my bash profile says: `# Add environment variable NDK_ROOT for cocos2d-x
export NDK_ROOT=/Users/damianwilliams/Desktop/Android-Development-Root/android-ndk-r10
export PATH=$NDK_ROOT:$PATH` amongst other exports.

Comment: What does "echo $NDK_ROOT" say?  You are on the right path.  You just need the native library.

Comment: /Users/damianwilliams/Desktop/Android-Development-Root/android-ndk-r10

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to go into Eclipse, right click my project and choose properties. In there I went to C/C++ Build, then Environment.

I clicked ADD, did NDK_ROOT for the name, and then the path for the value...

Worked a treat...